# ERROR 1772 ER_DISTRIBUTED_PARTITION_MOVE_FAILED: CREATE PARTITION DATABASE for operation `Create DB fail :Leaf Error reading from socket

Tags: database, singlestore

I created a test lab for Singlestore on my local PC. I have a Master, child, leaf 1, and leaf 2 node in docker containers. I can connect to singlestore studio and I can see the system databases. When trying to create a new database (create database JTest) I get the error:

> create database JTest ERROR 1772 ER_DISTRIBUTED_PARTITION_MOVE_FAILED:
> CREATE PARTITION DATABASE for operation `CREATE DATABASE` failed with
> error 2004:Leaf Error (172...:3306): Error reading from socket.
> Errno=104 (Connection reset by peer)

I have checked the memsql.log file and it looks like connection issues or something to the leaves.

Answer (score 0):

SingleStore version 7.8 now supports Flexible Parallelism, which allows multiple cores on the same node to access the same database partition.

With Flexible Parallelism, as database partitions are created they are divided into sub-partitions.

Go thru the official documentation of Singlestore for more info

Click [here](https://support.singlestore.com/hc/en-us/articles/5503478832660-SingleStore-7-8-Release-Announcement#:%7E:text=New%20Feature%3A%20SingleStore%20now%20supports,are%20divided%20into%20sub%2Dpartitions)